# Disable Vuetify styles for Katex elements - Shared class names like .accent lead to style issues

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, katex

I'm using Katex together with Vuetify. There is a problem with certain classes like accent or overline used by both Katex and Vuetify. This leads to weird stylings like the one you can see below. The overline characters got my accent styling.

I used a vue-katex component like this:

```
<katex-element expression="\hat A \overline{B} \widetilde{\phi}" />
```

This is how the equation looks like:

[image]

These are the vuetify styles:

[image]

This doesn't work:

```
.v-application .accent {
  all: unset !important;
}
```

How can I disable all Vuetify styles for katex-elements?

Answer (score 1):

There's an open issue on the KaTeX github about this: https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/issues/1456

You can either disable the Vuetify theme:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#disable-theme

```js
new Vuetify({
  theme: { disable: true },
})
```

Or use web components to isolate the KaTeX CSS, such as [katex-elements](https://github.com/justinfagnani/katex-elements) instead of vue-katex.

Comment: Thanks, disabling the theme does not fix the .overline issue. In my example the font size of the 'B' is smaller than expected.

Comment: Ah didn't know vuetify had an overline class too. I don't think there's an easy way to disable that, web components would be the best fix here.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem and putting this into one of my Vue components that uses Katex fixed it for me:

```css
<style lang="scss">
    span {
        .mord.accent {
            background-color: inherit !important;
            border-color: inherit !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```